# methods invoking, code understanding

Tags: java

I have a question in understanding one of the codes. I will really appreciate it if someone can help me understanding it.

[Here is the question in Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=20KFiaA60LQC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=What%20happens%20if%20the%20declaration%20of%20C%3a%20Class%20C%20%7B%20void%20process1&source=bl&ots=uDtaR--rjK&sig=joEC7T2abjbj1qsrNODwVvX4YFc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5o8mUvreJuewsQSlm4DgBw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=What%20happens%20if%20the%20declaration%20of%20C%3a%20Class%20C%20%7B%20void%20process1&f=false)

What happens if the declaration of C:

```
 class C {
 void process1(char ch) {
       System.out.println ("Inside process1 in C " + ch);     }
 void process2(char ch) {
   System.out.println ("Inside process2 in C " + ch);     }
 void process3(char ch) {
   System.out.println ("Inside process3 in C " + ch);
   process2(ch);  }                                            
 }
```

is followed by the following declaration of its extension:

```
class ExtC extends C {
  void processl(int n) {
     System.out.println ("Inside process1 in ExtC " + n);    }
void process2(char ch) {
     System.out.println ("Inside process2 in ExtC " + ch);   }
void process4(int n) {
     System.out.println ("Inside process4 in ExtC " + n);    }
}
```

Which methods are invoked if the declaration of three objects

```
 ExtC object1 = new ExtC( );
  C object2 = new ExtC( ), object3 = new ExtC( );
```

is followed by these statements:

```
 object1.process1(1000);
 object1.process4(2000);
 object2.process1(3000);
 object2.process4(4000);
 object3.process1(‘P');
 object3.process2('Q');
 object3.process3('R');
```

Question number 3.

I realized that it will first print
1- Inside process 1 in ExtC 1000
Then it will print
2- Inside Process 4 in ExtC 2000

But what then? What will happen in object2 and object 3 ? should I look at the Extend or Class C?

Comment: Please post the exact question here as opposed to providing a link to it.

Comment: http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-class-inheritance.html

Comment: Anyone with a very basic java knowledge will be able to answer this question. I would recommend however that you try to run the code examples as that alone will teach you way more than any java expert could. If you still need the answer, please post the question properly as arshajii suggested.

Comment: I have posted the question arshajii

Answer (score 0):

You know when we invoking a method,
compile time there check the method in the class denoted by the refference type
and in the run time it creates a instance of class denoted by the object type and check for the method there.
here the all the 3  objects are of ExtC class.ExtC class have actually 5 instance methods.process1(char ch) ,process2(char ch) ,process3(char ch) ,process1(int n) ,process4(int n): 
3 from its super class C.The process2(char ch)   has got overriden here.

consider the object1,refference type & object type both  are of ExtC.So there we can invoke all those 5 methods.
consider the object2,there we can invoke only the methods ,included in both classes i.e.2 classes denoted by refference type,'c' & object type ,'ExtC'.so the method process1(int n) & process4(int n) can't be invoked.
consider the object3,there we can invoke only the methods that included both in Object class(denoted by the refferece) & ExtC class .So non of those 5 can't be invoked.
now try for the answers again yourself.